# How to handle UITableView in UICollectionViewCell with interaction in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview, collectionview

I have project with structure like:
-*scroll view*
 --*view*
  ---*collection view*
   ----*collection view cell*
    -----*table view*
     ------*table view cell*

This structure is necessary for this project.
Every things works correctly like scroll view, collection view and table view but there is **interaction** just with **index 0** in collection view.
In other words ***didSelectRowAt*** method just call in **index 0**.

And i have uploaded my project on **GitHub**:

https://github.com/reza-khalafi/ScrollCollectionTable

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To fix the offset try using an auto resizable cell for UITableView

so in `setTableViewDataSourceDelegate` method just call

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```